# How to get started with windows phone SDK 8.1?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

**Situation:** 
I am running windows 7 professional and I am trying to start developing windows phone 8.1 application. 
I have downloaded :

- *[VS2013_RTM_DskExp_ENU.iso](http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/E/6/EE636CB6-D59E-4350-B8D3-5466A063E640/VSU2/vs2013.2_rm_enu.iso)* that is *Microsoft Visual studio 2013 Express RTM*.
- Since this is *RTM* update and windows phone 8.1 developement needs *2 RC updated*, I downloaded *[VS2013.2 RC.exe](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/D/9/FD9F1814-575D-4AA1-8B8D-DA82493E64BE/VSU2/VS2013.2%20RC.exe)*, which is online installer for the update mentioned. To download the full local installation package (3.43 GB), I ran `E:/vs/"VS2013.2 RC.exe" /layout` on command line.

For installation:

- I first installed *Microsoft Visual studio 2013 Express RTM*
- Then *2 RC update*.

Both of them installed sucessfully with no errors. But when I open *Visual Studio 2013>VS Express 2013 for Desktop* from start menu, and *File>New Project>Installed>Templates>Visual C#*, there is no option for windows phone development. That is what I want.

[image]

**Question:** How can I get the options to develop windows phone 8.1 in visual studio 2013 express using C#?

Comment: Check the [Visual Studio Web Site](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx). The only version of VS that supports Windows Phone is VS2012, and it requires a Windows 8.x (x64) development system.

Comment: @MikeW Actually there is a website for windows phone developers ( http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk ) which states that you can use VS 2013 to develop windows phone. Also refering Microsoft Download Center (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42307), they say that "windows 7 Service Pack 1" is also suitable.

Comment: It seems that development tools refer to IDE only, and you still need to download and install [Windows Phone SDK 8.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471) separately, which requires Windows 8 64 bit

Comment: @har07 Qouted from http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk :"The Windows Phone 8.1 development tools are included with Visual Studio 2013 (Update 2 or later). If you already have Visual Studio 2013 installed, use the download link to install Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 RC". This says that the download include the SDK

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows 8.1 is required to develop for Windows Phone 8.1

From the [SDK download page](http://dev.windows.com/en-US/develop/download-phone-sdk):

> For Windows Phone development:
>
> - Windows Phone 8.0 development requires Windows 8.1 (x64) or higher
> - Windows Phone 8.1 development requires Windows 8.1 (x86) or higher
> - For the Windows Phone emulators, Windows 8.1 (x64) Professional
>     edition or higher, and a processor that supports Client Hyper-V and
>     Second Level Address Translation (SLAT)

Comment: @Oliver Payen: can you tell me why they have mentioned so many other OS when one wants to download 2RC from this page: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42307

Comment: @Musa that's because you can work on other project types than WP8 with older OS versions: WinForm, WPF, ASP.NET, etc.

Comment: on https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-US/OEM/docs/Getting_Started/Preparing_for_Windows_Phone_development it says that you can develop on Windows 7 also. So which is the truth?

Comment: this link is broken now

Comment: I noticed that there are workaround for install sdk 8.0 in windows 7 but can't find one for sdk 8.1. Are the steps similiar? I can live without the emulator but would want to have the template and be able to open windows phone 8.1 project.