# Windows Phone 8.1/8 SDK

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

What installations I require for Windows Phone 8.1/8 SDK?

I have been through [How to get started with windows phone SDK 8.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23125570/how-to-get-started-with-windows-phone-sdk-8-1)
, but no luck.

Its ok if anyone wants to down vote. But please help me get through the installation. :)

Comment: What is that you don't understand from the linked question? You have to install VS 2013 on Windows 8. If you install VS 2013 on Windows 7, you don't get to develop for Windows Phone.

Answer (score 1):

You need Visual Studio 2013 update 2 or later. You can download the latest free version here:

[Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows with Update 3](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43729)

To run it you need at least Windows 8.1.

If you want to use the emulators, you need Windows 8.1 **Pro** x64, but if you have a physical Windows phone 8.1 device, you can use it to test your apps, instead of the emulators

Answer (score 1):

First of all for **windows phone 8/8.1** you would be needed to have **windows 8.1 (x64)Operating System**, Then you should check for whether your System is Supporting **Hyper-v** and **SLAT** or not.

To check for Hyper-V and SLAT, You can have Refrence from here [Does my processor support Hyper-V : Coreinfo](http://buildwindows.wordpress.com/2013/07/24/can-my-processor-support-hyper-v-coreinfo/)

If you have **Hyper-V** and **SLAT**, you are ready with Devlopment for windows phone 8/8.1.

for Development of windows phone 8/8.1 You would be needed to install **Visual Studio 2013** with update 2 or later. here is a download link for [Express 2013 for Windows](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx) that can be used for windows, windows phone as well as for Universal Apps.

for windows phone 8.1 emulators, you can download them from here [windows phone 8.1 emulators](http://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/download-phone-sdk)

Comment: Ok.. :) Unfortunately I can't check this until I reach home.. :(

Comment: I'll get back pretty soon.. Thanks.. :)