# Develop Windows Phone 8.1 apps on Windows 8

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I'm having o Windows 8 OS on my pc and Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 installed. 
Is it possible to develop apps on Windows Phone 8.1 in these conditions or an update to windows 8.1 is mandatory for this?

Comment: If yes, what sdk do I need to install? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get started with windows phone SDK 8.1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23125570/how-to-get-started-with-windows-phone-sdk-8-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows phone 8.1 apps are two types - Silverlight and Windows runtime.

If you are building a Silverlight app, you can target your app to Windows Phone 8 and work on it.

However, only when you want to develop a `Universal App`, you need Windows 8.1 since Windows Store apps, whether they run on phone / desktop have common runtime dependancies.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to update to Windows 8.1 to build Windows Phone 8.1 apps. You can build Windows Phone 8 apps on Windows 8 and run them on Windows Phone 8.1